# Mapping data from a IDbReader to their equivalent runtime types

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, oracle

I have looked for a handy way to read columns in a OraclaDataReader given the column name. Currently, I use something like:

```
int integer = (int)reader["Column1"];
int? nullableInt = reader.IsDBNull("Column2") ? null : (int?) reader["Column2"];
```

My question is: wouldn't it be possible to just create a generic extension method to deal with all this hassle? Something like reader.ReadInteger("Column"), **that can be used for nullable types, too?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an extension class should do that. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx 
but thats not very fast when y do that 1000 times in a row.

```
internal static class OraclaDataReaderExtension
{
    public static T Read<T>(this OraclaDataReader dbReader, string columnName)
    {
        return dbReader.IsDBNull(columnName) ? default(T) : (T)dbReader[columnName];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But that's not generic

Comment: Now, with much more generic. Only value-type works well.